# Better name for CHAR_BIT?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I was just [checking an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686542/converting-integer-to-a-bit-representation/2687562#2687562) and realized that `CHAR_BIT` isn't defined by headers as I'd expect, not even by `#include <bitset>`, on newer GCC.

Do I really have to `#include <climits>` just to get the "functionality" of `CHAR_BIT`?

Comment: What's the problem including `climits` or `limits.h`?

Comment: It just seems to be a lot of trouble (and potentially compiler time) to avoid writing the magic number 8.

Comment: Wait, are you asking for a different way of obtaining the information CHAR_BIT represents?  That makes more sense than my initial reading.

Comment: Try meassuring the difference between including that and not, and I bet that you will not notice any difference at all. Remember that *those willing to sacrifice correctness over performance deserve neither*. And we are talking about compilation time, not even runtime.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, although I would have been happy if another commonly-used header included `<climits>`.

Comment: @David: True, but it seems worth asking to see whether a no-sacrifice solution exists. After all, `CHAR_BIT` is a hackish macro just by itself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you may know, whether or not an implementation wants to include other headers is unspecified. It's allowed, but not mandated. (§17.4.4.1) So you either have to be explicit or know your guarantees.

The only time a C++ header *must* include another is if it requires a definition in another. For example, `<bitset>` is required to include `<cstddef>` for `std::size_t`, as this is explicitly stated in the standard. (§23.3.5, for this example)

For a counter-example, consider `<limits>`. It *may* include `<climits>` and define the values for `numeric_limits` in terms of the macros within, and it often does since that's easiest for an implementation. But all the standard says is things like: "*Equivalent* to `CHAR_MIN`, `SHRT_MIN`, `FLT_MIN`, `DBL_MIN`, etc." but doesn't say it *must* to be implemented in terms of those, which means `<climits>` doesn't have to be included.

So the only way you can be *guaranteed* that a `CHAR_BIT` is defined is by including `<climits>` or some other header where it's explicitly stated it must include it. And as far as I can tell, none have to; an implementation is free to just hard-code the value everywhere it's needed, for example, or include `<limits>` and use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` (which is equivalent).

Comment: You even answered the question in the title, and provided a better name for it!

Comment: Mostly unimportant trivia: Note that an implementation including other standard headers is allowed only for C++. In C, a compiler implementation is only permitted to define `CHAR_BIT` if `limits.h` is included. In fact, if `limits.h` isn't included by the user, it's perfectly OK (by the C standard) for the user to define `CHAR_BIT` himself for his own use - that identifier is only reserved if `limits.h` is included.  Not that I'd advocate that as a good idea, but it's OK as far as the C standard is concerned.

Comment: Important trivia: `numeric_limits<char>::digits` is equivalent to `CHAR_BIT` only if `char` is unsigned.  If `char` is signed, then it's equivalent to `(CHAR_BIT - 1)`, since the `digits` member doesn't count the sign bit.  I'd just go ahead and `#include <limits.h>` to get the number you want.

Comment: @Michael: You can do `unsigned char` like in the answer for the equivalent, too.

Comment: @GMan: I just wanted to specifically call out that you have to take care to use `unsigned char` and not just `char`.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, gotcha. :) One could also do `numeric_limits<char>::digits + numeric_limits<char>::is_signed`, but meh.

Answer (score 9):

Unless you're programming for DSPs, a better name for it is `8`. POSIX and Windows both require `CHAR_BIT==8`, and that covers pretty much every interesting target conceivable except DSPs. (I would not consider 1970s mainframes a potentially interesting target anymore, but perhaps someone will beg to differ...)

Comment: True nuff, but in a possibly complicated formula for calculating the size of a `std::bitset`, I'll be avoiding literal numbers like the plague.

Answer (score 6):

`<climits>` is where CHAR_BIT is required to be by the C++ standard.  Even if you happened to find it in `<bitset>`, its not guaranteed to be there, so you're better off going straight to the source.  Its not like there's something wrong with including `<climits>`.

Answer (score 3):

Define "newer". A random Linux system gave me these results:

```
~> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 (Gentoo 4.1.2)
[snip]

~> grep CHAR_BIT /usr/include/*.h
/usr/include/limits.h:#  define CHAR_BIT        8
```

Doesn't that qualify? In C, I think it [should always be enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h) to include `limits.h` to get `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should `#include <limits.h>` to get the definition of `CHAR_BIT`. It's not a bottleneck at all for your program (see comment below), and later down the line you might find yourself porting to different platforms. Not every implementation has the value of `8`

Comment: It's not a bottleneck for your program at all, since it's a macro that expands almost invariably to a constant. All the "work" happens at compile time.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Fixed the wording now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I keep the following function in my .profile to check compiler defined constants.  On my system `__CHAR_BIT__` is in there, which means no header is required if you can live with the double underscore form, which may only work with gcc.

```
defines () 
{ 
    touch /tmp/defines.h;
    cpp -dD "$@" /tmp/defines.h | awk '$1!="#"{COUNT+=1;print;}END{printf("count %d\n",COUNT);}' | sort;
    rm /tmp/defines.h
}
```

Comment: So you've got a platform-specific workaround to avoid including a header that was only required in order to avoid making assumptions about the platform in the first place?

Comment: It answers the question.  Is gcc a platform?