# Convert bit array to short

Tags: c++, byte, bit, short

I have a function that returns the bits of a short (inspired from [Converting integer to a bit representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686542/converting-integer-to-a-bit-representation)):

```
bool* bitsToShort(short value) {
    bool* bits = new bool[15];
    int count = 0;
    while(value) {
        if (value&1)
            bits[count] = 1;
        else
            bits[count] = 0;
        value>>=1;
        count++;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

How can I do the reverse? Converte the array of bits in the short?

Comment: With some bit/bitwise operators. Not sure if there's a better way/stdfunction

Comment: An implementation with 15-bit shorts does not conform to either the C or the C++ language definition. And even if it's changed to 16, that's a bad assumption to make without checking for overflow. Of course, that has nothing to do with the question. `<g>`

Comment: @PeteBecker An implementation where `short` has 15 value bits plus one sign bit does conform, and the code already doesn't deal with negative values properly (perhaps it doesn't need to) for other reasons, so if you ignore the sign bit, 15 bits remain.

Comment: @hvd - good point. The assumptions, then, are that `value` is non-negative **and** less than 2^16.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right, I can see that my comment wasn't very clear, but you got what I meant.

Comment: @hvd - your comment was clear. I added the qualification that the value is less than 2^16 because `short` can have **more than** 16 bits, and if it does, it can have values that are greater than 2^16, and this code won't handle them correctly.

Comment: @hvd - sorry, mentally replace "2^16" with "2^15" throughout all of my comments. I should know better than to post when I'm hungry.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `std::bitset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
short shortFromBits(bool* bits) {
    short res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        if (bits[i]) {
            res |= 1 << i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

`res |= (1<<i)` sets the i-th bit in `res` to one.

Comment: Thanks I'll accept the answer, but just one more question: why is not 40000 work? give me back 7232.

Comment: Because 40000 is larger than a short. (40000 & 0x7FFF) == 7232.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
bool* bits = ... // some bits here
short res = 0;
for (int i = 14 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    res <<= 1;             // Shift left unconditionally
    if (bits[i]) res |= 1; // OR in a 1 into LSB when bits[i] is set
}
return res;
```

Comment: In the code given, bits[0] is the LSB; in your code, bits[0] would be the MSB. Downvoted (sorry about that).

Answer (score -1):

Essentially:

```
unsigned short value = 0;
for (int i = sizeof(unsigned short) * CHAR_BIT - 1; 0 <= i; --i) {
    value *= 2;
    if (bits[i)
        ++value;
}
```

This assumes that `bits` points to an array of `bool` with at least `sizeof(unsigned short)` elements. I have **not** tested it. There could be an off-by-one error somewhere. But maybe not.